# new node registered with same name- arduino

Tags: ros, arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have 2 arduino mega connected to 2 usb ports. When i rosserial one is forced to shut down because it says new node registered with same name. This i think because the node.initNode() in both files. In arduino , i cant specify the name of the subscriber node.

How can i overcome this problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215225/new-node-registered-with-same-name--arduino/) by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2015-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try running each rosserial_python with a different `__name` argument? See [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments) for a more detailed definition

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB0 __name:=node1

rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py /dev/ttyUSB1 __name:=node2
```

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2015-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2